# net-snmp on start says - "Error opening specified endpoint " in Raspberry pi - Jessica

Tags: raspberry-pi3, debian-jessie

My raspberry pi - jessica has got snmpd --version

NET-SNMP version:  5.7.2.1
Web:               http://www.net-snmp.org/
Email:             net-snmp-coders@lists.sourceforge.net

Now, I am trying to make a subagent application and running it.
When I try to run this I get the following error -

```
$ sudo snmpd -f -Lo -C --rwcommunity=public --master=agentx --agentXSocket=tcp:localhost:1705
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
pcilib: Cannot find any working access method.
pcilib: pci_init failed
error on subcontainer 'ia_addr' insert (-1)
Turning on AgentX master support.
Error opening specified endpoint ""
Server Exiting with code 1
```

Why I get this error? Here is my snmpd.conf file.

```
###############################################################################
#
# EXAMPLE.conf:
#   An example configuration file for configuring the Net-SNMP agent ('snmpd')
#   See the 'snmpd.conf(5)' man page for details
#
#  Some entries are deliberately commented out, and will need to be explicitly activated
#
###############################################################################
#
#  AGENT BEHAVIOUR
#

#  Listen for connections from the local system only
agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161
#  Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 *and* IPv6)
#agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161



###############################################################################
#
#  SNMPv3 AUTHENTICATION
#
#  Note that these particular settings don't actually belong here.
#  They should be copied to the file /var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf
#     and the passwords changed, before being uncommented in that file *only*.
#  Then restart the agent

#  createUser authOnlyUser  MD5 "remember to change this password"
#  createUser authPrivUser  SHA "remember to change this one too"  DES
#  createUser internalUser  MD5 "this is only ever used internally, but still change the password"

#  If you also change the usernames (which might be sensible),
#  then remember to update the other occurances in this example config file to match.



###############################################################################
#
#  ACCESS CONTROL
#

                                                 #  system + hrSystem groups only
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1

                                                 #  Full access from the local host
#rocommunity public  localhost
                                                 #  Default access to basic system info
 rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly

                                                 #  Full access from an example network
                                                 #     Adjust this network address to match your local
                                                 #     settings, change the community string,
                                                 #     and check the 'agentAddress' setting above
#rocommunity secret  10.0.0.0/16

                                                 #  Full read-only access for SNMPv3
 rouser   authOnlyUser
                                                 #  Full write access for encrypted requests
                                                 #     Remember to activate the 'createUser' lines above
#rwuser   authPrivUser   priv

#  It's no longer typically necessary to use the full 'com2sec/group/access' configuration
#  r[ow]user and r[ow]community, together with suitable views, should cover most requirements



###############################################################################
#
#  SYSTEM INFORMATION
#

#  Note that setting these values here, results in the corresponding MIB objects being 'read-only'
#  See snmpd.conf(5) for more details
sysLocation    Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
sysContact     Me <me@example.org>
                                                 # Application + End-to-End layers
sysServices    72


#
#  Process Monitoring
#
                               # At least one  'mountd' process
proc  mountd
                               # No more than 4 'ntalkd' processes - 0 is OK
proc  ntalkd    4
                               # At least one 'sendmail' process, but no more than 10
proc  sendmail 10 1

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::prTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table will be empty if there are no "proc" entries in the snmpd.conf file


#
#  Disk Monitoring
#
                               # 10MBs required on root disk, 5% free on /var, 10% free on all other disks
disk       /     10000
disk       /var  5%
includeAllDisks  10%

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::dskTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table will be empty if there are no "disk" entries in the snmpd.conf file


#
#  System Load
#
                               # Unacceptable 1-, 5-, and 15-minute load averages
load   12 10 5

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::laTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table *will* be populated, even without a "load" entry in the snmpd.conf file



###############################################################################
#
#  ACTIVE MONITORING
#

                                    #   send SNMPv1  traps
 trapsink     localhost public
                                    #   send SNMPv2c traps
#trap2sink    localhost public
                                    #   send SNMPv2c INFORMs
#informsink   localhost public

#  Note that you typically only want *one* of these three lines
#  Uncommenting two (or all three) will result in multiple copies of each notification.


#
#  Event MIB - automatically generate alerts
#
                                   # Remember to activate the 'createUser' lines above
iquerySecName   internalUser       
rouser          internalUser
                                   # generate traps on UCD error conditions
defaultMonitors          yes
                                   # generate traps on linkUp/Down
linkUpDownNotifications  yes



###############################################################################
#
#  EXTENDING THE AGENT
#

#
#  Arbitrary extension commands
#
 extend    test1   /bin/echo  Hello, world!
 extend-sh test2   echo Hello, world! ; echo Hi there ; exit 35
#extend-sh test3   /bin/sh /tmp/shtest

#  Note that this last entry requires the script '/tmp/shtest' to be created first,
#    containing the same three shell commands, before the line is uncommented

#  Walk the NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB tables (nsExtendConfigTable, nsExtendOutput1Table
#     and nsExtendOutput2Table) to see the resulting output

#  Note that the "extend" directive supercedes the previous "exec" and "sh" directives
#  However, walking the UCD-SNMP-MIB::extTable should still returns the same output,
#     as well as the fuller results in the above tables.


#
#  "Pass-through" MIB extension command
#
#pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255  /bin/sh       PREFIX/local/passtest
#pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255  /usr/bin/perl PREFIX/local/passtest.pl

# Note that this requires one of the two 'passtest' scripts to be installed first,
#    before the appropriate line is uncommented.
# These scripts can be found in the 'local' directory of the source distribution,
#     and are not installed automatically.

#  Walk the NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB::netSnmpPassExamples subtree to see the resulting output


#
#  AgentX Sub-agents
#
                                           #  Run as an AgentX master agent
 master          agentx
                                           #  Listen for network connections (from localhost)
                                           #    rather than the default named socket /var/agentx/master
#agentXSocket    tcp:localhost:705
```

Answer (score 9):

It's probably too late for Bali Vinayak, but might help others with like issue.
On an Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, NET-SNMP version: 5.7.3 I solved the same error setting `snmpd` to use TCP instead instead of UDP.
So edit `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`:

```
agentAddress  tcp:127.0.0.1:161
```

Then I got no error running the startup command:

```
systemctl start snmpd.service
```

Comment: You probably should do a restart. Start did nothing for me, I assume because it thought it was already running even though it was not, but it gave no error and did not start until I stopped it.

Comment: After trying 10 different things this worked for me. I wish snmpd properly logged this issue so it would be properly debuggable.

Comment: Happy to see my experience helped you out.
I agree, many error messages and log entries are too vague, generic and of little help.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it by edit /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf to this:

```
# agentaddress  127.0.0.1,[::1]
agentaddress  127.0.0.1
```

Comment: This resolved my case since I got an error message from snmpd when it tried to open a IPv 6 connection on "[::1]"

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file.

Search for

```
trapsink localhost public
```

and add :162 after localhost, such as

```
trapsink localhost:162 public
```

Reference: https://github.com/net-snmp/net-snmp/issues/34

Answer (score 1):

There is also another, simpler case which results in the "Error opening specified endpoint" message. Because other posts seem to be referencing to this at least indirectly, I will post it under this topic also. See my case:

```
root@am335x-evm:~# /etc/init.d/snmpd stop
Stopping network management services: snmpd snmptrapd.
```

Then trying to start snmpd manually:

```
root@am335x-evm:~# /usr/sbin/snmpd -Lo -a -f
Error opening specified endpoint "127.0.0.1"
Server Exiting with code 1
```

But look:

```
root@am335x-evm:~# ps aux | grep snmp
root       562  0.4  3.7  30944  9168 ?        Ssl  18:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/snmpd -Ls0-6d -a -f
root       570  0.0  1.9   8880  4792 ?        Ss   18:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/snmptrapd -Lsd -f
root       692  0.0  0.6   2352  1636 pts/0    S+   18:21   0:00 grep snmp
```

So, the init script did not actually stop it. Stopping it properly:

```
root@am335x-evm:~# systemctl stop snmpd
root@am335x-evm:~# ps aux | grep snmp
root       570  0.0  1.9   8880  4792 ?        Ss   18:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/snmptrapd -Lsd -f
root       708  0.0  0.6   2352  1520 pts/0    S+   18:24   0:00 grep snmp
```

Then trying running:

```
root@am335x-evm:~# /usr/sbin/snmpd -Lo -a -f
NET-SNMP version 5.8
```

It works.

Comment: For me, this suggestion helped me find a snap snmp daemon still running. Killed it, removed snap, and restarted the snmpd daemon. Thanks for the suggestion.